# Demostration De-Morgan's theorem for 4 variables?

Tags: logic

Algebraically demostration De-Morgan's theorem for 4 variables

I didn't find the answer for my question, therefore I'll ask here

My demostration

a v b v c v d = a v b v (c v d) = a v (b v( c v d) )

(a v b v c v d) = ¬ (av(bv(cvd))) = ¬ (a) ^ ¬(bv(cvd)) =
¬(a)^(¬(b)^¬(cvd)) = ¬(a)^ ¬(b) ^(¬(cvd)) =

=  ¬(a) ^¬(b) ^(¬(c) ^¬(d)) = ¬ a∧¬ b∧¬ c ∧ ¬ d.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Could you please provide more details? In particular, please show what you have tried yourself.

Comment: ¬ (a∨b∨c∨d)=¬ (a∨ b (c∨d )) =  ¬ a∧¬ b ∧ (c∨d) = ¬ a∧¬ b∧¬ c ∧ ¬ d

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: here it is for three variables; you can figure out the generalization:
$$
\neg\left(a\vee b\vee c\right)=\neg\left(a\vee\left(b\vee c\right)\right)=\neg a\wedge\neg\left(b\vee c\right)=\neg a\wedge\neg b\wedge\neg c.
$$

Comment: ¬ (a∨b∨c∨d)=¬ (a∨ b (c∨d )) = ¬ a∧¬ b ∧ (c∨d) = ¬ a∧¬ b∧¬ c ∧ ¬ d